# Visualise percentage of sales over time Power Bi for each salesman

Tags: excel, database, powerbi, visualization, dax

I have a dataset that looks like.

```
+------------+-------+----------+--+
|    Date    | Sales | Salesmen |  |
+------------+-------+----------+--+
| 12/31/1999 |   100 | P1       |  |
| 12/31/1999 |   100 | P2       |  |
| 12/31/1999 |   300 | P3       |  |
| 01/31/2000 |   500 | P2       |  |
| ...        |       |          |  |
| 07/31/2020 |   500 | p3       |  |
+------------+-------+----------+--+
```

But I want to visualise this as a line chart (with multiple lines for each salesmen), as a percentage of the total sales per salesman per year and visualise it over the full 20 year period(1999-2020)yearly.

Power BI for visualising lines has 3 fields:
**Axis** , **Legend** and **Values**.
I placed date in axis, Salesmen in legend and for values I created a measure of the Sales(displayed "As a % of Grand total" option), however it doesn't return what I would like it to.

[image: %GT Measure]

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM('Table1'[Sales]),FILTER('Table1','Table1'[Date].[Year]=2020))
```

However this only returns percentage values of the sum total for 1 year.

[image: Line graph of visualisation with above measure]

and the visualisation outputs a table that looks like.
[image]

So I used another measure

```
Measure = SUMX(CALCULATETABLE('Table1','Table1'[Date].[Year]), 'Table1'[Sales])
```

however this reverts the same value for each year.

[image: Measure 2 Chart]

However this produces a table that looks like:
[image]

I need it as a sum total of sales per year split as percentage among the 3 salesmen, then visualised.
So I know there's something I'm missing in the measure, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these following step-

**Step-1:** Create a measure to calculate total sales as below-

```
total_sales = SUM(Table1[sales])
```

**Step-2:** Create a measure that will calculate SUM of amount per year as below-

```
current_year_sales = 

var current_row_year = MIN(Table1[Date].[Year])

return 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Table1[sales]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Table1),
        Table1[Date].[Year] = current_row_year 
    )
)
```

**Step-3:** Now create the final measure as below. Convert this measure type to %

```
year_wise_percentage = [total_sales]/[current_year_sales]
```

**Spet-4:** Configure your line chart as below-

```
Axis: Year
Legend: salesmen
Values: year_wise_percentage
```

You should have your expected output now.

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani, Thank you ofr the prompt response, I have applied the steps you outlined perfectly howver the visualisation is still incorrect, it gives me values which are too small, in the range of 0.000 to 2.00000E-5

Comment: Did you converted the measure "year_wise_percentage" type as percentage (%)?

Comment: I have converted it, still same issue.

Comment: @NEWishLearner, can you share 3 measures you written?

Comment: the three measures are the same as above:
1) total_Sales = SUM('Table1 (2)'[Date])
2)current_year_Sales = 

var current_row_year = MIN('Table1 (2)'[Date].[Year])

return 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table1 (2)'[MV_M]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table1 (2)'),
        'Table1 (2)'[Date].[Year] = current_row_year 
    )
)
3)year_wise_percentage = [total_Sales]/[current_year_Sales]

Ive shown the value as %of GT as well.

Comment: Hi @NEWishLearner - 1. Why you are passing "'Table1 (2)'[Date]" date value for calculating the SUM? And finally - no need shown the value as %of GT I guess.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't notice that I did that. It works great. I multiplied the value by 100 to get it as that percentage instead pf using %GT

Comment: Hi @NEWishLearner, nice to hear it worked and helped :)